# What causes blueimp jQuery File Uploader to fail out of the box?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I downloaded blueimp jQuery File Uploader and released it into my public_html. Out of the box it's supposed to work with the demo pages provided but it is giving me a "Internal Server Error". I have upload enabled in my php.ini with file size 50 MB which is well high enough for the files I am trying to test with.

Can anyone give some pointers about how to debug errors coming from blueimp jQuery File Uploader because there is very little documentation on debugging it.

Comment: Look at the browser's console to see what, if any, errors you're getting and then work from there.

Comment: Sorry - should have mentioned - no errors in browser console and no error_log file in php.

Comment: How about the HTTP error log?

Comment: Where can I find that?

Comment: It depends on your server, but all servers have access and error logs.

Comment: Can you please give me some ideas about how to find out what the 500 is?

Comment: Do you have error logging enabled? 500 error typically means an error occured within your server-side script, hence, "internal server error"

Comment: Yes error logging is enabled

Comment: Did you look at the logs that were generated by the 500 server error?

Comment: They didn't generate any. That's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the issue on this... Using commenter's advice I checked out the 500 error log file which was at /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log. There was error that my server/php directory was writeable by the group... After doing a chmod g-w on the directory, it worked fine.

Thanks!